# Overwrite the Default Messages in redux-form-validators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-form-validators

I am having difficulty overwriting the default error message in `redux-form-validators` using the code suggested by the docs:

```
Object.assign(Validators.messages, {
    required: "This is a required field"
})
```

This gives an error

> Validators is not defined

**Problem:** What is this `Validators` object and where/how should we define/use it so that we can overwrite the default messages properly?

**/containers/Animals/Animals.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { required } from 'redux-form-validators';
import { renderTextField } from './FormHelpers';

class AnimalForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Object.assign(Validators.messages, {                // ERROR OCCURS HERE
            required: "This is a required field"
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>                     
                        <Field
                            label="Longitude"
                            name="location.coordinates[0]"
                            component={renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                            validate={[required()]}
                        />  
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
    form: 'animal'
})(AnimalForm))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to do the validation using the inbuilt functionalities of `redux-form` so that you have more control over your codebase. And it'll be better to seperate your forms rather than putting them in containers which feels a bit weird. I would normally do something like the following:

I have created a stateless component for the form since we aren't planning to change the state inside this component.

**forms/animal.form.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { renderTextField } from './FormHelpers';
import validate from './validate';
import submit from './submit';

let AnimalForm = (props) => {

  const {
    handleSubmit, submitting,
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>                    
        <Field
          label="Longitude"
          name="longitude"
          component={renderTextField}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

AnimalForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'animal',
  onSubmit: submit,
  validate,
})(AnimalForm);

export default AnimalForm;
```

When you try to submit the form using the "Submit" button, the validate function will be called from `validate.js`. Do all your validations inside this function. You can even use regex to validate.

**forms/validate.js**

```js
const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.longitude) {
    errors.longitude = 'This is a required field';
  }
  return errors;
};

export default validate;
```

Once there are no validation errors, submit function from `submit.js` is called.

**forms/submit.js**

```js
function submit(values, dispatch, props) {

  // PERFORM YOUR OPERATIONS HERE AND DISPATCH ACTIONS

  const body = {
    longitude: values.longitude,
  };

  dispatch(createAnimal(body));

}

export default submit;
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to globally override messages, use the `Object.assign` method in your `index.js` or some global place - doing it inside a component is an extremely bad idea. To do so globally:

```
import Validators from 'redux-form-validators'

Object.assign(Validators.messages, {
    required: "This is a required field"
})

// or 

Object.assign(Validators.messages, {
  required: {    
    defaultMessage: "This is a required field"
  }
})
```

Looking at your sample code, if you want to override it just for the component, then doing it locally is much better:

```
<Field
    label="Longitude"
    name="location.coordinates[0]"
    component={renderTextField}
    type="text"
    validate={[required({msg: "This is a required field"})]}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Validators to your import

```
import { Validators, required } from 'redux-form-validators'
```